# Can anyone tell me what type of woodworm this is, and what to use to kill it?

Tags: wood, shelving, insect

There's a video [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmlb3feqv2x71lh/29724876_413085445809842_851164670122262528_n.mp4?dl=0) of a woodworm beetle poking it's head out of a hole, that i filmed on my phone with a little macro lens.  I'd already treated the wood with [this water-based woodworm killer](https://www.cuprinol.co.uk/products/woodworm_killer.jsp), and and I think this guy was poisoned enough that he couldn't crawl out of the hole, and was just sort of slowly thrashing about.

This was in an oak shelf board.  I've found a couple more bodies poking half out of other holes, in that and other shelves.  More holes are appearing though so there's obviously still more of them.

Looking at [this page](https://www.timberwise.co.uk/woodworm-treatment/what-do-woodworm-look-like/), I think it might be the Common Furniture Beetle (I'm in the UK and this is a European species).  That's based on the little blobs at the end of its antennae, or whatever they are.

I still have three shelves with new woodworm holes occurring periodically.  I've taken them down and put them out the way in the utility room.

Can anyone a) confirm what this is and b) recommend a more powerful treatment, since the last one didn't completely work?

Comment: If you would put the shelves in a plastic bag and put it out in the sun it might get hot enough to kill all the worms without damaging the shelves.

Comment: @JimStewart great idea, thanks, I will look into that.  I'm guessing lots of black bin liners taped up to seal the gaps would work well?  Would reduce the chance of them falling on my toddler daughter as well which is starting to be a bit of a worry